# three.js ES6 how import only specific modules

Tags: javascript, three.js, browserify, babeljs, es6-modules

I've installed [three.js](https://threejs.org) library through NPM to get advantage of the new ES6 modular architecture which should let you to import just the modules you need, as explained here: [Threejs - Import via modules](https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/introduction/Import-via-modules).

I am using [gulp](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwim-rr-lJvZAhXqBcAKHbwRDEoQFggoMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgulpjs.com%2F&usg=AOvVaw0pR3721kJ0KIv8N3GeJdlZ), [browserify](http://browserify.org) and [babel](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjbp52QlZvZAhWDzRQKHQB0D28QFggoMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fbabeljs.io%2F&usg=AOvVaw0h9OdJQHZ6TcgcMH6KMOX1) for bundling and transpiling, like so:

```
gulp.task("build_js", () => {

return browserify({
    entries: "./public/app/app.js",
    cache: {},
    dev: true
})
    .transform(babelify, {presets: ["env"], plugins: ["syntax-async-functions", "transform-async-to-generator"], sourceMaps: true})
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source("app.bundle.min.js"))
    .pipe(buffer())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: mode}))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write("./"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.build.js))

});
```

I want to import only the modules I need and keep the bundle size small, but I noticed that the bundle generated by browserify has the same size regardless if I import all the modules or just one.

If in app.js I import all the modules I got a bundle size of about 500Kb:

```
// app.js

import * as THREE from 'three'; // about 500 Kb size
```

But if I try to import just a specific module using ES6 syntax I got the same bundle size (it is importing again all the modules):

```
// app.js

import { Vector3 } from 'three'; // about 500 Kb size, same as before example
```

I've also tried the following:

```
// app.js

import { Vector3 } from "three/build/three.module.js";
```

But I got the following error:

```
SyntaxError: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level (45590:0) while parsing /Users/revy/proj001/node_modules/three/build/three.module.js
```

My question: how can I properly import only the modules I need and keep the bundle size small?

Comment: What happens if you try `import {Vector3} from 'three/src/math/Vector3`

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the concept of [Tree Shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/).

When you import a modules by name the other modules are **not** automatically removed from the bundle. The bundler always includes every module in the code and ignores what you have specified as import names.

The other unused modules, which you did not import, are considered dead code because they are in the bundle however they are not called by your code.

So to remove this unused code from the bundle and thus make the bundle smaller you need a minifier that supports dead code removal.

Check out this popular tree shaking plugin for browserify - it should get you started:

https://github.com/browserify/common-shakeify

Comment: I don't understand. When I import a module, I expect that only the code relevant to that module will be imported (and the modules required from that module in a transitive dependency path). This is not dead code, it is the code that I need in my application. The modules that are not in transitive dependency path should not be imported, or am I missing something?

Comment: The bundler always includes everything except if you use a tree shaking tool. Your assumption that only the code which you explicitly import is included is wrong.

Comment: i'm not an expert on this topic, but this does seem wrong. If you `import {Vector3} from './path/Vector3` you've **only imported `Vector3`** not everything else? How is it possible otherwise, what's the part that imports the rest of the modules?

Comment: Is it because of `... from 'three'`? ` from `path/wherever/ThreeClass` should work?

Comment: Yeah i guess this makes sense, `from 'three'` imports all and produces dead code, which can be tree shaken. However, directly importing from the module, shouldn't result in dead code?

Comment: pailhead you got it right and that is basically what my answer says

Comment: @pailhead I've tried to import from "../node_modules/three/src/math/Vector3" directly but it fails with error:
<<'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level (45590:0) while parsing...>>.
I found that using something like https://github.com/nolanlawson/rollupify solves the issue but still I am bit confused about this new ES6 import/export system and which it is its purpose if I am forced to import all the modules if I just required one.

Answer (score 1):

Solved using [rollupify](https://github.com/nolanlawson/rollupify) inside browserify transform. It will perform tree shaking and remove dead code:

```
gulp.task("build_js", () => {

return browserify({
    entries: "./public/app/app.js",
    cache: {},
    dev: true
})
    .transform(rollupify, {config: {}})    // <---
    .transform(babelify, {presets: ["env"], plugins: ["syntax-async-functions", "transform-async-to-generator"], sourceMaps: true})
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source("app.bundle.min.js"))
    .pipe(buffer())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: mode}))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write("./"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.build.js))

});

}
```

Still I would appreciated an explanation on why ES6 module import works like this..